# Should I work on CSS or apps first?

Tags: html, css, django, python

I am working on my own website for my business, and I need to contract out some assistance.  For example, I have the site looking pretty good on Firefox, but it needs help on other browsers.  I also need some help with adding some Django apps to the site and setting up a database.  I plan to seek the help of two different individuals via elance or odesk.  My question is which to do first - get the css and html right then do the apps, or get the apps done and then work on the css and html?  Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[IE Bug Fixes](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/9-most-common-ie-bugs-and-how-to-fix-them/)

I would personally get a strong template down before working on any crazy features. Do the HTML/CSS then move on to the APPs. It might help attract good freelancers if you have everything else done.

Comment: Thanks.  That was what I was thinking.  I originally posted the job with both tasks included, but I'm getting little response, which has led me to believe that separating them will make it easier.  Sorry I can't upvote your answer yet, I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @Fred: Does that not completely answer your question? <a href="djangogigs.com">DjangoGigs.com</a> for you Django project. What kind of database where you planning on setting up? Depending on your needs / webhost, you might have a really simple solution that won't require you to employ a freelance.

Comment: Yes that completely answered my question.  I need 3 things on the site:  1) a way for me to post job openings and have people apply online or just submit an application to be held on file if no positions are available, 2)a way for customers to log in and give feedback on the service they received and 3) a way for employees to log in and find evaluation information and possibly scheduling information at some point in the future (depends on budget).  I know that I could fix the CSS and get all these things working, but it would take me 10x as long as getting an expert.

Comment: @Fred: What web host are you using? Do you have any idea of what kind of database engine you would use?

Comment: Webfaction.  I chose it because its a good Python hosting site with mod_python access.  I'm not sure if I'm going to use a mysql or a sqlite db.

Comment: @Fred: <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3630/sqlite-vs-mysql">Here</a> is a good description of the pros/cons of both MySQL and SQLite. Judging from that answer, I would say that you want to use MySQL. Webfaction has built-in MySQL support - I would recommend using that. As far as building the database, you could do it yourself. However, being able to interact with it programmatically would require you to learn PHP. I can describe what you would need to do both parts of this if you'd like.

Comment: I had read that question and I re-read it.  It actually convinced me that a sqlite db would work just fine for me.  I don't need enterprise-level sophistication.  Also, regardless of the db I choose, I prefer to use Python to interact with it.